# Batch script Find multiple value from text file to another text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the sample lookup file

```
Remote working directory is /
New local directory is D:\PP
local:PP65205861.PDF => remote:/PP65205861.PDF
Listing directory /
-rw-------   1 200      100         12414 June 03 20:05 PP65205861.PDF
New local directory is D:\PE
local:PE65205861.PDF => remote:/PE65205861.PDF
Listing directory /
-rw-------   1 200      100          6763 June 03 20:05 PE65205861.PDF
New local directory is D:\TEMP
Listing directory /
*.PDF: nothing matched
```

Source1 file value/s to look in lookup file

```
PE65205861.PDF
```

Source2 file value/s to look in lookup file

```
PP65205861.PDF
```

Current log output

```
local:PP65205861.PDF => remote:/PP65205861.PDF
 -rw-------   1 200      100         12414 June 03 20:05 PP65205861.PDF
local:PE65205861.PDF => remote:/PE65205861.PDF
 -rw-------   1 200      100          6763 June 03 20:05 PE65205861.PDF
```

**Desired log output**
Plus setting a value to a variable to be used in other validation.

```
PE65205861.PDF
PP65205861.PDF
```

Comment: does this give you the desired result? `for /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%a in (yourfile.log) do echo(%%a`

Comment: This will do the trick, how come i never thought of that. btw thanks.

Comment: This will work if the log file you're parsing keeps the format you posted. It may need some adjustment of the `tokens` and `delims` if it changes, but you're on the way. ;-)